# MVC Helpers Library for HTML Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, libraries, helper

This is probably a silly question, but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Are there any MVC Helper Libraries, specifically for Form type controls.

For example, I want to achieve HTML for a Label like:

```
<label class="form-label-left required" for="message">Message: <span>*</span></label>
```

Unfortunately the built in helper doesn't allow you to specify anything on the label. (as far as I'm aware)

Other examples are being able to specify input types:

```
<input type="email" name="EmailAddress" />
```

And other types such as 'tel', 'range', 'number', etc, from HTML5.

So are there any libraries that give you more control over this sort of thing, or is it better to just write my own helpers?

**Update:**

I found this in my RSS Feed for The Morning Brew.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Html5MVCWebControls.aspx

A library for HTML5 controls. Still seems there's a lack of Customizable or HTML5 libraries for MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the ASP.NET MVC source code and come up with custom helpers. Here's an example of the Label with required indicator.

```
public MvcHtmlString CustomLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

    string resolvedLabelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText))
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    if (metadata.IsRequired)
    {
        var spanTag = new TagBuilder("span");
        spanTag.AddCssClass("required-star");
        spanTag.InnerHtml = "*";

        resolvedLabelText = string.Concat(resolvedLabelText, spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }

    var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
    tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
    tag.InnerHtml = resolvedLabelText;
    tag.AddCssClass("text_label");

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I actually wrote something similar but it didn't occur to me to use the metadata to work out if it's required or not. Thats cool. I'm wondering is it worth creating my own lib for all this stuff, or is there any libs already that do a lot of this stuff so I'm not creating a new type of wheel.

Comment: @Phill there are plenty of 3rd party libraries. Eg [MVC Contrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/), [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx). I tend to write my own for some simple tasks.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what MVC Contrib was when I was looking at it yesterday, it looks like it wants to do everything, I couldn't find anything which sais 'heres a bunch of helpers available'. Telerik I wont touch at all, their Web Form controls were terrible.

Comment: @Phill yes. MVCContrib documentation and samples are not adequate. But there are samples and how tos in blogs.